# How to stop run javascript function when asp.net webform loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm write this code for show my position on the map:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
   <script>
       function initialize(x, y) {
           alert(x);
           alert(y);
           var mapProp = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
               zoom: 5,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
       }
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

up code run the initialize function when page load or postback,but i write this code for asp button:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "beh", "initialize(38.076306,46.279637);", true);
```

and i want when button fire,send value to function and java script function change the map position,it's work,but when button fire,function run ,and run again when web form loaded!,and in first time show correct position,but when page load event occurred,send null value to function and show empty position, i think when run java script function in asp button fire,and not run java script function when page load occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is the execution order of the code blocks. Execution time of code that is added via the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` according to the `msdn`:

> The script block added by the RegisterStartupScript method executes when the page finishes loading but before the page's OnLoad event is raised.

So, you could solve your problem by adding a `boolean variable` in your `script` tag (which get's executed while the page is loading), set it to `false` initially and change it to `true` in your `button click handler` (which is executed once the page has finished loading). Then in your `window.onload` event listener, check if the variable is `false`. If it is, you can initialize the map.

So, your `javascript` would change to this:

```
<script>
    var isButtonClick = false;
    function initialize(x, y) {
        var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { if(!isButtonClick)initialize(0, 0) });
</script>
```

and your `button click handler` to this:

```
void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "beh", "isButtonClick=true;initialize(38.076306,46.279637);", true);
}
```

I tested it locally and it worked fine

Comment: Thanks my friend to pay attention to my problem,now i vote up you.